# How to get auth user in boot method inside a model?

Tags: php, laravel

When I call `auth()->user()` in the model.
and the result is null.

is it possible to call `auth()->user()` in the model ??

and this is my code

```
 /**
 * The "booting" method of the model.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->created_by = auth()->user()->id;
    });

    static::updating(function ($model) {
        $model->updated_by = auth()->user()->id;
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .. `auth()->user()` will work as long as that request is passed by `auth()` midleware

Comment: It's not clear where the issue might be here. Can you share a small code sample that would help us reproduce your issue?

Comment: @apokryfos okay, I've edited it

Comment: This will all depend on when a model is actually created or updated. `auth()->user()` will only work after the AuthServiceProvider has ran and (if you are using the session authentication) the `StartSession` middleware has been executed. If you create or update a model before this happens (e.g. a controller constructor) then `auth()->user()` will be null

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view composer or share data directly with all views using a closure in boot method.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
public function boot(): void
{
    View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $view->with('current_user', $user);
    });
}
```

Comment: This will perform a potentially unnecessary query on every page with a view, though.